# Yii Framework , TbGridView Fildname inactive

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I have a problem , i have 2 tables users and data , relation is one to one , here is code for dataProvider

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Users', array(
    'pagination'=> array(
        'pageSize'=> 10
    ),
    'criteria'=>array(
        'with' => array (
            'data'=>array(
                'joinType'=>'JOIN')
            )
        ),
    )
));
```

and relations `'data' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Data', 'id');`

and code for TbGridView

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'template'=>"{items} {pager}",
    'itemsCssClass'=>'table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed tableNews',
    'columns'=>array(
        array('name'=>'id', 'header'=>'#'),
        array('name'=>'name'),
        array('name'=>'email'),
        array('name'=>'data.id'),
        array('name'=>'data.investment_amount')
));
```

for second table i have to put data.fildname , else is not working , and fildnames of second table is not clickable  [image: screenshot of TbGridView]

what can be the problem , thank you

Comment: check this http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/281/searching-and-sorting-by-related-model-in-cgridview/

Answer (score 0):

```
   
        return new CActiveDataProvider("Users", array(
          'criteria'=>$criteria,
          'sort'=>array(
          'defaultOrder'=>$defaultOrder,
          'attributes'=>array(

            'id'=>array(
                        'asc'=>'t.id',
                     'desc'=>'t.id DESC',
                ),


            'data.investment_amount'=>array(
                        'asc'=>'data.investment_amount',
                     'desc'=>'data.investment_amount DESC',
                ),
```

but if you use `sort` you need to define all names inside attributes array